# New-Partition -DriveLetter Option

Tags: powershell

How do I create a single char variable in PowerShell?

I am using the following script to format new virtual disks added to our Windows 2016 servers. The problem is, Microsoft does not give any examples of what it wants for the -DriveLetter option. I can't figure out what it wants. A single character, I get that, but why is "s" wrong?

```
$driveletter = "S"
Get-Disk | Where-Object partitionstyle -eq raw |
    Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru |
    New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -DriveLetter $driveletter -UseMaximumSize |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "App" -Confirm:$false
```

The error I repeatedly get is:

> New-Partition : Invalid Parameter
>   Activity ID: {6fab380c-c0df-4f8d-bdca-f0fed3250238}
>   At line:1 char:22
>   + ... -Number 2 | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -DriveLetter $drivelette ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [New-Partition],
>      CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,New-Partition

Once the drive is online I keep trying with:

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber 2 -AssignDriveLetter -DriveLetter $driveletter -UseMaximumSize |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "App" -Confirm:$false
```

To no avail.

Microsoft's documentation on this command says it wants a Char and gives no information on how to give it that.

Comment: Just as a side-note, I haven't had the best luck with the disk-/drive-oriented cmdlets in Windows 10 [tag:powershell] and often fall back to `diskpart`.  Can you post your full exception message?  If you're trying to pass an explicit char, you can typecast your string: `$driveletter = [char]'S'`

Comment: One problem here is that you are using `-DriveLetter` and `-AssignDriveLetter` together. `-AssignDriveLetter` will automatically assign a drive letter from the first available letter in the pool.

Comment: Updated the error in the post. I really prefer to use powershell if I can because it's easier to integrate with CloudBolt. I don't think diskpart would work for that.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks I'll try removing that part.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks that did the trick, in addition to the previous comment on how to cast as char.

Comment: You'd think it would have thrown an incompatible parameter error instead?

Comment: I would love it if Microsoft were more detailed about their documentation and error messages. If they'd said "use this option instead of -AssignDriveLetter" it would have made all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was two fold:

Create the char variable like this:

```
$driveletter = [char]"S"
```

And secondly, remove the -AssignDriveLetter option as this is redundant and unnecessary with -DriveLetter.